# How to transfer funds from one account to another in java, using user input for each desired account, and amount to transfer

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to create and execute a method which allows the user to choose an account from which and an account to which the user wants to transfer an amount, which the user also chooses. But, I don't know how to get user input asking from and to which class they want to transfer funds to.

I've tried using the Scanner method but I can't get it to work.

Here is the code, it's the same as the code beneath this but this is easier to view imo: https://gist.github.com/KamronKelley/32d9a40c285e501f64cf73fa28bf87b5

```
package banking;

public class Account {
    String name;
    double balance;

    public Account() {
        name = "";
        balance = 0.0;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void addFunds(double addedAmount) {
        balance = balance + addedAmount;
    }

    public void withdraw(double withdrawnAmount) {
        balance = balance - withdrawnAmount;        
    }

    public void transfer(double amount, Account from, Account to) { //here is the transfer method, if i can improve this or alter it in order to make it easier to run using user input from the main file, let me know
        if(from.balance >= amount){
            from.balance = from.balance - amount;
            to.balance = to.balance + amount;
            System.out.println("Funds successfully transfered.");
        } else {
                System.out.println("Insufficient funds");
            }
        }
    }

package banking;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankSimulator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println("Hello and welcome to the banking system. Please enter a name to create an account, no spaces: ");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            Account a1 = new Account();
            a1.setName(scan.next());
            System.out.println("Account name: " + a1.getName());

        int count = 0;
        while(count == 0) {

                System.out.println("What would you like to do next?"  + "\n" +
                "Change account name: press 1"  + "\n" +
                "See account name: press 2"  + "\n" +
                "Check balance: press 3"  + "\n" + 
                "Add money to balance: press 4"  + "\n" +
                "Withdraw money from balance: press 5" + "\n" +
                "Exit program: press 7: " + "\n" +
                "To transfer funds between accounts: press 6");

                int toDo = scan.nextInt();

            if(toDo == 1) {

                    System.out.println("Enter new account name: ");
                    a1.setName(scan.next());
                    System.out.println("Account name: " + a1.getName());
            }
            else if(toDo == 2) {
                System.out.println("Account name: " + a1.getName());
            }
            else if(toDo == 3) {
                System.out.println("Current balance: $" + a1.getBalance());
            }
            else if(toDo == 4) {
                System.out.println("Desired amount to add: $");
                a1.addFunds(scan.nextDouble());
                System.out.println("Money successfully added to balance."); 
            }
            else if(toDo == 5) {
                System.out.println("Desired amount to withdraw: $");
                a1.withdraw(scan.nextDouble());
                System.out.println("Money successfully withdrawn from balance.");
            }
            else if(toDo == 6) {
                System.out.println("Enter the account you would like to transfer money from:");
                String fromAccount = scan.next();
                System.out.println("Enter the account you would like to transfer money to:");
                String toAccount = scan.next();
                System.out.println("Enter the amount of money you would like to transfer: $");
                double moneyToTransfer = scan.nextDouble();
        //this is what i need help with, I don't know what to do with these three things, and since the first two arent accounts, i cant run the transfer method on them


            }
            else if(toDo == 7) {
                System.out.println("Thank you for using our banking system. Until next time.");
                count = 1;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't do anything with the user input because I need the desired accounts in order to run the transfer method with them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of all the accounts in a List or  maybe a Map. Then you using the user input you search and retrieve the desired accounts. Also I don't think you need the transfer method in the Account object you can just use withdraw and addFunds from the main, or maybe have it like a static method. Also I think you will need a few additional operations, like create new account and maybe a login that will just change the active account. Currently you only have 1 account which is a1 so it makes no sense to transfer anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are saying, I already checked your code but I think there's a bit of redundant code in there, like your "Account from". If you are the owner of an account and you are transferring to another do you need to specify your account number? You understand?

Secondly, it's best your multiple ifs and else-ifs to switch case statements.

```
class bankAccount {
String name;
private double balance;
private final long acctNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(100000000, 999999999);

public bankAccount(String name, double balance) {
    this.name = name;
    this.balance = balance;
    System.out.println("HELLO " + name + ", Your account number is: " + acctNum);
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void addFunds(int amount) {
    this.balance += amount;
}
public void withdrawFunds(int amount) {
    this.balance -= amount;
}
public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}
public long getAcctNum() {
    return acctNum;
}
public void transfer(bankAccount name, double amount) {
    if(this.balance >= amount) {
        name.balance += amount;
        this.balance -= amount;
        System.out.println("Transaction Successful");
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Insufficient Funds!");
    }
}
}

class BankSimulator {
static bankAccount John = new bankAccount("John", 50000);
static bankAccount James = new bankAccount("James", 3000);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    John.transfer(James, 300);
    System.out.println("John's new balance is "+ John.getBalance());
    System.out.println("James' new balance is "+ James.getBalance());
}

}
```

since you'll be making use of another `account`, you should create  two instances of the `Account` class, this would clarify the ambiguity between which accounts to transfer to.

Essentially all I did was create the Account class, created an instance named `John`(John's Account) and create an instance named `James` (James' Account), so now, There you go with two account classes, with different fields but similar methods `(getBalance(), transfer(), getAcctNum(), addFunds(), withdrawFunds())`.

I Hope this is what you need, Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create dummy data (existing) Account first:

```
  List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
  Account acct1 = new Account("tester1", 100.0);
  Account acct2 = new Account("tester2", 100.0);
  accountList.add(acct1);
  accountList.add(acct2);
```

Add constructor for Account for easier adding of Accounts:

```
    public Account(String name, double balance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
```

Store new account account in list:

```
accountList.add(a1);
```

For your procedure for "(toDo == 6)" which is for transfer:

Check first if accountList has at least 2 accounts because it won't make sense if there's only 1 account.

```
else if (toDo == 6) {
  if (accountList.size() > 2) {
    System.out.println("Enter the account you would like to transfer money from:");
    String fromAccount = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the account you would like to transfer money to:");
    String toAccount = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of money you would like to transfer: $");
    double moneyToTransfer = scan.nextDouble();

    for (Account account : accountList) {
      if (account.getName().equals(fromAccount)) {
        account.withdraw(moneyToTransfer);
      }
      if (account.getName().equals(toAccount)) {
        account.addFunds(moneyToTransfer);
      }
    }
  } else 
    System.out.println("Cannot transfer.");
  }
```

Also consider if the account actually exists, so add additional checking. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

I know this conversation was from awhile ago, however, must mention to definitely Not use a static method as anthony suggested in this type of situation because a static method can only access static variables and methods.